# What will be the best way to add footer, which will be at botton regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: android, android-layout, footer

I am developing an application, where I need to put two buttons at the bottom regardless of any screen resolution.

What will be best to implement this?

Comment: what you have searched uptill so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RelativeLayout with` a `LinearLayout` at the bottom. Just one way to do it , and use `layout_weight` to set buttons with equal size.

**Updated**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idBtn1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/idBtn2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

set those buttons inside an new layout ( Relative / Linear - respective to your layout view ) and give `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: Screen XML design is already ready with LinearLayout, I want solution with LinearLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to use footer for common use:

First create one `footer.xml` file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >   
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/idFooterMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/footerBtn1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button1" />   
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/footerBtn2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button2" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then you can use this `footer.xml` file in any other screen **without repeating the code again**.

```
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Thanks.